# advise me how to create a good print in wpf?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

i want to print in wpf like Cristal report of win application. in fact i want the abilities of Cristal report like tabling and sorting,... in wpf. but i didn't see any control in wpf' tool box.
please advise me how to create a good print in wpf.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same control (Windows crystal report viewer) in your WPF application. Look at the the following link for sample code.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2988ae8-e7b8-4a62-a34f-b851aaf13886

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you have FlowDocument and FixedDocument for the same.
For details refer to [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).